# Windows - Automatic log-in, then log off after first log-in only

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

My current understanding is that when you log in, selected startup programs start to load. These do not start loading until you log in.

Even with an SSD, having multiple programs run at boot requires a decent amount of time before the PC can be used smoothly. My startup programs are Flux, Steam, Skype, Dropbox, Anti virus, Google Drive, Custom mouse features, download manager, Pushbullet, Nvidia Shadowplay - quite a few!

I'm not interested in a startup delay/stagger program.

Perhaps a batch script could be made to run at boot.
 - (Make log-in be automatic)
 - Count number of logins to computer since power on, X
 - If X = 1, press "Windows key + L" to lock the computer

Edit:
Found a solution! Gonna check it now.

http://lifehacker.com/5645098/make-windows-load-your-desktop-before-you-log-in

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 and Windows 10 the Task Scheduler is the best "built-in" option I've found to do this.

### Procedure

1. Press Start button and search for Task Scheduler and open it.
2. On the right side of the screen, under Actions/Task Scheduler Library 
   click "Create Task..."
3. Under the "General" tab click the radio button next to "Run whether user is logged in or not"
4. Under "Triggers" tab, select the "At startup..." option at the top next to Begin the task... .
5. Under "Actions" tab, select the "Start a program option" and "Browse" to the file you'd like run a startup. If you'd like multiple programs it's advisable to create a batch script, as proposed in the question, and run that.

Review through Conditions as Settings and customize the task as necessary. Be sure to test with a reboot!